# Use path argument of display in fitler criteria

Tags: views

I have a view which displays all terminology terms from a specific terminology.

The view also have a display with a `path=/taxonomy/term/%` so if I go to "details page" of a specific term, the display is used.

This works fine expect that it, of course, that the view filters for all terms in that terminology. I now want to only show the `%` one.

Can I somehow use the `%` in my filter criteria?

I think that what I want is to use the parametric value `%` inside "Configure filter criterion: Taxonomy term: Term ID"

Answer (score 0):

The `%` sign corresponds with an argument. Within views, these are known as contextual filters (advanced section).

If you add a contextual filter for `taxonomy id` and provide a numeric value for the % it should work. You also get options for what to do when % is empty, etc.